# Why do some files in my visual studio code appear darker?

Tags: heroku, visual-studio-code, filesystems

[image: this is how it looks]

I am using this to program a backend that is deployed in heroku.
The images that are shown darker appear in my local server but once deployed they can't be seen. Any ideas?

Comment: Check your gitignore ?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, but now i have another. I have heroku and github connected but the server saves the images locally. So even if i change the gitignore, the images are not pushed to the branch and are not accessible from the server.

Comment: share your gitignore and your folder tree, it is possibly get answer.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, but the problem was that those files didnt appear in the master branch. That's why they were grey.